# create new attributes from dynamically created textboxes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to create new attributes for a selected node by getting the value of dynamically created textbox inside a panel when a listbox item is selected. Am sure you didnt unsderstand nothing from what I just said so am giving you a pic to have an idea.

[image]

So the problem after I reload the xml file I see this this thing inside the node

`d3p1:DisplayFormat="" xmlns:d3p1="gh"`

Here is the code am running

```
if (addEl.Count != 0)
{
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load(xml);

    XmlNode pnode = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Class[@Name='" + currentClass + "']/Property[@Id=" + pList.SelectedItem + "]");
    for (int i = 0; i < availableProperties.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        string selecteItem = availableProperties.SelectedItem.ToString();
        Control[] controls = table2.Controls.Find("txt" + selecteItem, true);

        foreach (Control item in controls)
        {
            foreach (string n in addEl)
            {
                    pnode.Attributes.Append(xDoc.CreateAttribute(n, item.Text));
                    xDoc.Save(xml);
                    ok = true;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

The xml structure as it was asked. Sorry I forgot to put this

```
<Root>
  <Class Name="ECMInstruction" Style="Top">
    <Entity Id="1" Name="DocumentInformation" />
    <Entity Id="2" Name="CustomerInformation" />
    <Property Id="1" Name="DocumentTitle">
    </Property>
    <Property Id="2" Name="DateCreated">
      <Lists>
        <ListName>ws_Users</ListName>
        <ListName>dfdfdfd</ListName>
      </Lists>
    </Property>
    <Property Id="3" Name="Deadline">
    </Property>
  </Class>
  <Class Name="AlphaCertificationsIndividual" Style="Top">
    <Entity Id="1" Name="DocumentInformation" />
    <Property Id="1" Name="DocumentTitle">
    </Property>
    <Property Id="2" Name="DateCreated">
      <Lists>
        <ListName>ws_Users</ListName>
        <ListName>dfdfdfd</ListName>
      </Lists>
    </Property>
    <Property Id="3" Name="Deadline">
    </Property>
  </Class>
</Root>
```

Comment: Adding the XML you are manipulating would help a lot. My guess is; you need to create the new attributes in the correct namespace. -> xDoc.CreateAttribute(n, item.Text) needs a "namespace" instead of attribute name and value only.

Comment: no no namespace. just attribute name and value from textbox. I just added the xml structure to the question

Comment: why are people voting to close this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
pnode.Attributes.Append(xDoc.CreateAttribute(n, item.Text));
```

try this one, with appropriate attribute name and values.

```
pnode.Attributes.Append(xDoc.CreateAttribute("MyNewAttrib")); 
pnode.Attributes["MyNewAttrib"].Value = "newval";
```

Answer (score 0):

`CreateAttribute()` doesn't have [overload that accept attribute value as parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you can do this in one line like so :

```
pnode.Attributes.Append(xDoc.CreateAttribute(n, item.Text));
```

The 2nd parameter above [specifies namespace URI of the attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtyc931d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that's why you got undesired prefixed attribute. You need to assign the attribute value later on as also suggested in the other answer :

```
pnode.Attributes.Append(xDoc.CreateAttribute(n));
pnode.Attributes[n].Value = item.Text;
```